# Spring Boot Custom connection object

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have the elasticsearch 5.4 transport client connection.

```
@Configuration
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elastic.host}")
    private String esHost;

    @Value("${elastic.port}")
    private int esPort;

    @Bean
    public TransportClient client() throws Exception {

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
        return client;
    }

}
```

I need to get the instance inside service class to use it in my operation.

```
@Service
public class ElasticService {

    TransportClient client;

    public String getInfo(){
          client.methodCall() ...
    }

}
```

How can I autowire the client object defined inside ElasticService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
@Service
public class ElasticService {

    @Autowired                    <---- add this annotation
    TransportClient client;

    public String getInfo(){
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to spring boot. I thought I can autowire ESConfig and call client method everytime. I guess Spring container will look for the correct  Bean type and autowire it automatically ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I suggest you to read the Spring Boot reference guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/